# Экспорт таблицы из базы MySql, автоматическое редактирование

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

Существует таблица в базе данных MySql. Задача скачать её и привести данные в другой формат в файле .data (или txt, потом переименую) из файла txt:

В такой:

```
1072870863|ally@комментарий
1071404087|enemy@комментарий
1080167444|ally@комментарий
1077589396|enemy@комментарий
```

из такого

```
|1072870863|ally|комментарий
|1071404087|enemy|комментарий
|1080167444|ally|комментарий
|1077589396|enemy|комментарий
```

Или есть вариант легче?

Понял как с помощью CONCAT() решить свою задачу, но в VS на код

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT CONCAT(field1, "|", field2, "@", field3, "") AS list INTO OUTFILE 'table.data' FROM table", db.getConnection());
```

выдал вот такие ошибки, не знаю как это обойти.

В phpMyAmdin данная команда прекрасно работает, проблема у меня с VS.

[image: Ошибки VS]

Comment: Не понимаю, где Вы нашли проблему... не знаете о существовании функции CONCAT(), что ли?

Comment: Не знал, я ещё ноль. Эту функцию нужно на локальной скачанном уже дампе использовать или в phpMyAdmin ещё?

Comment: Эту функцию следует использовать в SELECT clause запроса SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE.

Comment: Это сработало, спасибо. Но в VS теперь выдаёт ошибки на код

Comment: приложил скриншот

Comment: А за кавычками кто будет следить??? ```MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT CONCAT(field1, '|', field2, '@', field3) INTO OUTFILE 'table.data' FROM table", db.getConnection());```

Comment: УРА! Заработало)